# How to link a split view controller to a window controller?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I want my window controller to display a split view controller as it would do with any view controller, but I can't link them by ctrl dragging from my split view controller to the window controller...

[image]

How can I solve my problem ?
Tahnk you

Answer (score 10):

A bit late, but you control drag from the Window Controller icon at the top of the Window Scene to the Split View Controller Scene. Hope this helps someone else.

[image: Interface Builder]